# symfony 4 - All pages only for logged

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I need to "close" my application only for logged users (not matter roles) so I have set `access_control` into:

```
access_control:
         - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/forgot-password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN] }
```

but I can still go into `^/` or any another page (except `admin`) as guest. What is bad? Here is my firewalls:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
```

Comment: for `main`, you've forgot to add `pattern: ^/`

Comment: @Cid Still same, config cleared, `pattern: ^/` pasted like in updated code above.

Comment: Before I change my security to use Annotation I had something like that, for my admin part `- { path: ^/admin/*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }`, you could try that. Also, if I remember well, the  IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY means the user "manually" logged in only, the user that are login thanks to the "remember me" option won't access it. That last point is to be confirmed in the Security Component docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
 access_control:
    - { path: ^/(register|login)?$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/?$, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have and ordered Roles and access_control like:

```
security:
    ## Previous parameters

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

In the `firewalls` section

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/ #The most important in your case
        logout: true
        anonymous: true
```

Then in the `access_control`section you can do like this:

```
access_control:
     #LOGIN
     - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/forgot-password, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     #Default
     - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_AGENT }
```